# ReactJS local vs global state and implementing redux at a later time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, single-page-application, react-redux

So we are about two months in on a project. This is the first time I have ever managed code writers and not written the code myself. I've been reading their code for the last week. What was suppose to be a simple React app has turned into a spaghetti mess.

I understand: redux helps to manage global state. But should that mean that all buttons should map to a global "action?" This has seemed to create this entire mess of objects scattered throughout the entire app. I keep asking myself, why are we using global state for everything when local state could be used for 90% of the application. This is the kind of code that gives me heartburn:

```
let subitems = SidebarItems[state.type].sub_items;
Store.dispatch(SidebarSubItemHandler(item.action, subitems[0], null));

if(item.sub_items[subitems[0]].param) {
    browserHistory.push(`${item.sub_items[subitems[0]].path}/${item.sub_items[subitems[0]].param}`);
} else {
    browserHistory.push(item.sub_items[subitems[0]].path);
}

subItembuttons = Object.keys(this.props.subitems.sub_items).map(subitem => {
    let subItem = this.props.subitems.sub_items[subitem];
    return <li className={this.props.activeSubItem.action == subItem.action ? "bottom-bar-item active" : "bottom-bar-item"}
               onClick={e => this.props.onClickSubItem(e, subItem)}
               key={subItem.action} style={this.props.subitems.inlineStyles.mobileSubItemLI}>
        <a href="">{subItem.item}</a>
    </li>;
});
```

The application is littered with all kinds of objects like these that map to "action" objects. So at this point we are making the decision to scrap the entire project and restart from scratch, but without redux. Let's try to do as much as possible using local state only. When it comes time, and we need global state for something, ONLY implement it for that something, not every single action in the app. Does this make sense?

So I guess my question is: If we develop an app using local state and just fundamental React, will we be creating un-reversable problems that would prevent us from implementing redux on a per item basis?

Comment: I think providing more of the file in the example code snippet will help people see the context of the spaghetti code in your codebase.
There isn't anything explicitly wrong with using both local state and global state together. I think showing more of the code will help to see what concepts or principles of the React/Redux architecture are not being followed by the developers who are writing that code.

Comment: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1287

Voila, the answer from the maker himself. A good use case for redux is when you want to decouple state from your UI components. Mixing state and components is sometimes inevitable, but having them mixed up can get very dirty quickly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the relevant Redux FAQ entry at http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-only-redux-state:

> **Using local component state is fine**. As a developer, it is your job to determine what kinds of state make up your application, and where each piece of state should live. Find a balance that works for you, and go with it.
>
> Some common rules of thumb for determing what kind of data should be put into Redux:
>
> - Do other parts of the application care about this data?
> - Do you need to be able to create further derived data based on this original data?
> - Is the same data being used to drive multiple components?
>   Is there value to you in being able to restore this state to a given point in time (ie, time travel debugging)?
> - Do you want to cache the data (ie, use what's in state if it's already there instead of re-requesting it)?

Per your specific question: if you use the "container component" pattern fairly consistently, it should be relatively straightforward to swap those "plain React" containers for Redux-connected containers down the line.  See https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/react-component-patterns.md#component-categories for articles on the "container/presentational component" pattern.

Two other thoughts.  First, I recently co-authored an article that discusses [why you might want to use Redux in a React application](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/redux-with-mark-erikson/).

Second: yeah, that code looks kinda ugly.  I'm hoping those are at least three different snippets from different parts of the codebase, rather than one snippet, but that's rather hard to read.  The repeated use of "sub_items" and "subitems" seems like a bit of a red flag, readability-wise.

It also doesn't look like it's following good Redux practices.  For example, idiomatic Redux code almost never references the store directly.  Instead, references to `dispatch` and `getState` are available via middleware, and thus can be used in action creators via `redux-thunk` and `redux-saga`.  Connected components can also access `dispatch`.

Overall: you are absolutely welcome to use as much or as little Redux as you want, and as much or as little local component state as you want.  I think the larger issue, though, is how well your team actually understands Redux, and how they're trying to use it.

Comment: If we hook a component up to redux in the future, can we still use local state for small things in that component?

Comment: Absolutely.  As that quoted FAQ entry says, "**Using local component state is fine**".

Comment: Hope you don't mind if I ask you one more thing. We have currently managed to accomplish all global tasks by passing down 1 object {handlers} down via this.props from the parent-most component. This seems so easy! Why would people switch to redux versus passing down a handlers object of functions??

Comment: If you're only passing down a few values, or only passing them down a couple levels, that doesn't take much work. However, as the app grows, you generally end up with the top component "required" to know every piece of data that every nested component needs, and having to pass props down _many_ levels. Redux simplifies that process by allowing any component to specify exactly what data it needs from the store, and what actions it wants to dispatch. That means better perf, simpler components, and more readable code.

Comment: Instead of passing independent props I just have two objects. Data and handlers. So I can add as many props as I want to data object, and still only have to pass 2 things only. Every time I try to read the redux tutorial I just think god this is so over complicated.

Comment: Redux does add some indirection for some tasks. For others, it makes them much simpler.  You might want to read through http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/CoreConcepts.html , https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367 , and a presentation I just gave that has a small intro to React and Redux: http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/02/presentation-react-redux-intro/ .

Comment: thanks for good explanation, one question came in my mind when we use redux everything goes in global store, how different it is from global state which we usually try to avoid?How good it is to keep everything in store and not using prop drilling at all?